# AllowAutoRedirect in windowsPhone

Tags: c#, httpwebrequest, windows-phone-8, httpclient

In HttpClientHandler have propertie AllowAutoRedirect, but on build app for WindowsPhone throw exception:

HttpClientHandler.AllowAutoRedirect is not supported on this platform.  Please check HttpClientHandler.SupportsRedirectConfiguration before using HttpClientHandler.AllowAutoRedirect.

I really want to prevent autoredirect.
I tried to use HttpWebRequest:

```
    var client = (HttpWebRequest) WebRequest.Create(connectionUrl);
client.Headers["AllowAutoRedirect"] = "false";
client.Method = "GET";
client.Headers["UserAgent"] = @"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.31 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/26.0.1410.43 Safari/537.31";
client.ContentType = "application/json";
client.Headers["ContentLength"] = client.ToString().Length.ToString();
client.BeginGetResponse(Callback, client);
private void Callback(IAsyncResult ar)
{
var requestState =(HttpWebRequest) ar.AsyncState;
using (var postStream = requestState.EndGetRequestStream(ar))
{}
}
```

this code throw exception on EndGetRequestStream: "Value does not fall within the expected range"
I look forward to your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are receiving the `ArgumentException: Value does not fall within the expected range` because you are initiating a `BeginGetResponse()` on the client but then doing a `EndGetRequestStream()` in your callback where instead you should call `EndGetResponse()`. Setting `AllowAutoRedirect` works fine you just need to fix your code. Try this:

```cs
  var client = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(connectionUrl);
  client.AllowAutoRedirect = false;
  client.Method = "GET";
  client.BeginGetResponse(Callback, client);

  private void Callback(IAsyncResult ar) {
      var state = (HttpWebRequest)ar.AsyncState;
      using (var response = state.EndGetResponse(ar)) {
          var streamResponse = response.GetResponseStream();
          var streamRead = new StreamReader(streamResponse);
          var responseString = streamRead.ReadToEnd();
      }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not use HttpClient with and HttpClientHandler??

```
HttpClientHandler clientHandler = new HttpClientHandler();
clientHandler.AllowAutoRedirect = false;

// Create an HttpClient using the HttpClientHandler
HttpClient client = new HttpClient(clientHandler);
```

More info: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/henrikn/archive/2012/08/07/httpclient-httpclienthandler-and-httpwebrequesthandler.aspx

Comment: Dude, I have asked it two years ago. But in any case, thanks for try to help